# Search phrase in a sentence using Lucene 5.5

Tags: search, lucene

Purpose: To build a dictionary (Sample Dictionary taken from Gutenberg project). This application should have the capability to return the "word" is part of the meaning is provided. Example:

CONSOLE
Con*sole", v. t. [imp. & p.p. Consoled; p.pr. & vb.n. Consoling.]
Etym: [L. consolari,. p.p. consolatus; con- + solari to console, comfort: cf. F. consoler. See Solace.]

Defn: To cheer in distress or depression; to alleviate the grief and raise the spirits of; to relieve; to comfort; to soothe. And empty heads console with empty sound. Pope. I am much consoled by the reflection that the religion of Christ has been attacked in vain by all the wits and philosophers, and its triumph has been complete. P. Henry.

Syn. -- To comfort; solace; soothe; cheer; sustain; encourage; support. See Comfort.

So if my query is "To cheer in distress", it should return me "Console" as the output.

Am trying to build this tool using Lucene 5.5 (lower versions won't do for now). This is what I tried:

Indexing:

```
Document doc = new Document();<br>
doc.add(new Field(MEANING, meaningOfWord, Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));<br>
doc.add(new Field(WORD, word, Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));<br>
indexWriter.addDocument(doc);<br>
```

Analyzing:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();<br>
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(MEANING, analyzer);<br>
parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);<br>
parser.setAutoGeneratePhraseQueries(true);<br> 
Query query = parser.parse(".*" + searchString + ".*");<br>
TopDocs tophits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000);<br>
```

This (tophits) is not returning me what I want. (I have been trying Lucene from  last week or so, so please excuse if this is very naive). Any clues?

Comment: Found the solution, use WildCardQuery, like this: WildcardQuery wildCardQ = new WildcardQuery(new Term(MEANING, searchString));

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a different analyzer was used when the documents were indexed.  Probably `KeywordAnalyzer` or something.  You (usually) need to pass the same analyzer to IndexWriter when indexing your documents as the one you will use when searching.  Also, bear in mind, after correcting the IndexWriter's analyzer, you will need to reindex your documents in order for them to be indexed correctly.

Wrapping what should be a simple phrase query in wildcards is a *extremely* poor substitute for analyzing correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution, use WildCardQuery, like this:

WildcardQuery wildCardQ = new WildcardQuery(new Term(MEANING, searchString));

But for incorrect words/phrases, it sometimes takes long time to come back with the answer.

Comment: There is a reason you have to set a flag to allow leading wildcards.  Leading wildcards make your queries very slow.

Comment: Can you suggest a solution? No? I will go with this for the time being.

Comment: Just because I did not write it there, does not mean that I had not already tried it :(.